# How to update the text inside a window?

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to create my first GUI Application. I just want to display a text(could be a number maybe), and then in a loop change/update it. I found some basic examples to create and display a window, with some text, but how do i update the text? 
Could someone please show me a simple example? A good example would be displaying the time.

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Here is my code. It is nothing special, i just took an example from MSDN.

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T( "win32app" );
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T( "Win32 Guided Tour Application" );

HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
WNDCLASSEX wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_APPLICATION ) );
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_APPLICATION ) );

if ( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
{
    MessageBox( NULL, _T( "Call to RegisterClassEx failed!" ), _T( "Win32 Guided Tour" ), NULL );

    return 1;
}

hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

if ( !hWnd )
{
    MessageBox( NULL, _T( "Call to CreateWindow failed!" ), _T( "Win32 Guided Tour" ), NULL );

    return 1;
}

ShowWindow( hWnd, nCmdShow );
UpdateWindow( hWnd );

HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
// Main message loop:
MSG msg;
char test[ 100 ] = { 0 };
int i = 0;
while ( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
    i++;
    hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    sprintf(test, "%d", i);
    TextOutA( hdc, 5, 5, test, strlen( test ) );

    EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    TranslateMessage( &msg );
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
}

return ( int )msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
 {
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
TCHAR greeting[] = _T( "Hello, World!" );

switch ( message )
{
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );

        TextOut( hdc, 5, 5, greeting, _tcslen( greeting ) );

        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will depend completely on what GUI framework you are using.

Comment: I am using the standard Windows GUI. WndProc

Comment: @kampi - You can use either `SetWindowText` or `SetDlgItemText` or you can explicitly send the message `WM_SETTEXT` (both functions do this for you internally). E.g `SetWindowText(hWnd, ptrToTextToSet);`

Comment: @enhzflep: SetWindowText updates the titlebar. I have a GUI which displays a text, and that text should be updated, not the title bar. Or am i doing somethin wrong?

Comment: If you posted your code we could see what you're doing and give relevant suggestions rather than random guesses.  No matter how you're displaying it you should be able to change it and cause the window/control to redraw with the updated data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do all your drawing in the WM_PAINT handler in your message loop between the BeginPaint/EndPaint calls, otherwise it'll get overwritten.

Here's an example that displays the time.  I use a timer to invalidate the window which generates a WM_PAINT message but you can do it a different way if you like.

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInst;
HWND hWnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            SYSTEMTIME time;
            GetLocalTime(&time);
            wchar_t timeString[30] = {};
            GetTimeFormatEx(nullptr, 0, &time, nullptr, timeString, 30);
            RECT clientRect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);
            DrawText(hdc, timeString, -1, &clientRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_TIMER:
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, false);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TestClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    RECT sz = {0, 0, 128, 64};
    AdjustWindowRect(&sz, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, TRUE);
    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"TestClass", L"Test Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, sz.right - sz.left, sz.bottom - sz.top,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if(!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, nullptr);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Do not do the drawing in your loop.
2) Only draw in WM_PAINT
3) Create a variable that contains what you want to draw
4) If you want to redraw your window, call InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, NULL) and it will post a WM_PAINT message to your window proc.
5) I'd suggest creating a timer that redraws maybe once every 5 seconds. Ideally, you would redraw when something changes the state of your data.  If you redraw every time through your message loop, it's going to continuously redraw and be very unresponsive.
```

Answer (score 2):

This example shows you how a number is printed in the center of the window and incremented and updated whenever your press with the left mouse button anywhere on the window's client area.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

LRESULT __stdcall wndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void register_window_class(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;
    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = "wndclass";
    wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);
}

HWND create_window(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        "wndclass",
        "My first window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800,
        600,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    return hwnd;
}

int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    try{
        register_window_class(hInstance);
        HWND hwnd = create_window(hInstance);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

        MSG msg;
        while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(...){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

LRESULT __stdcall wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    static int iCount = 0;
    static char buffer[256];

    switch(msg){

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            ++iCount;
            snprintf(buffer, 256, "%d", iCount);
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_CENTER);
            TextOut(hdc, rect.right / 2, rect.bottom / 2, buffer, strlen(buffer));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

So when you click with the left mouse button, the message

```
WM_LBUTTONDOWN
```

is sent to your window procedure by Windows. Whenever that occurs, a static int is incremented, written to a char buffer. Finally, the call

```
InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
```

invalidates the window's entire client area. This means that WM_PAINT will be called because there is a portion of the client area that is invalid. Also, the last argument which is set to true makes sure that when

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

is executed, the invalid section of the client area is painted over with the background brush specified in the window class. This effectively erases any previous window contents so that

```
TextOut(hdc, rect.right / 2, rect.right / 2, buffer);
```

has a clean area to write on.

It is a good habit to structure your program so that all information is accumulated so a complete re-paint can be done in WM_PAINT (basically quoting the Win32 bible "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzold).